# How to kill rsync gently?

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

I'm running rsync on a large number of files, and I want to kill the process without leaving any partial files. Is there a way to kill the process gently? I've been looking through the manpages for rsync and kill, but I can't determine if SIGSTOP or SIGTERM will allow rsync to finish its current file before terminating.

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `rsync` man page:

```
EXIT VALUES
   0      Success
   ...
   20     Received SIGUSR1 or SIGINT
   ...
```

so it would seem that either of these signals can be used to stop a transfer.